# Failed to call service from aspnetboilerplate asp.net-core project controller

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

Work on **Aspnet core boilerplate framework** stuck on one issue, form my controller failed to call services.

Application class library contains **IEmployeeService** and **EmployeeService**, how to call them from my **EmployeeController**.

**Service**

```
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        int CreateEmployee(CreateEmployeeDto data);
        IEnumerable<EmployeeListDto> GetEmployeeList();

    }
 public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [AbpMvcAuthorize]
    public class EmployeeController : HRISControllerBase
    {


        private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

        public EmployeeController(           
            IEmployeeService employeeService
           )
        {

            _employeeService = employeeService;           
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Note: Do project need to configure something in ConfigureServices on the Startup.cs file.

Comment: check out  @aaron answer. you have to register your service with `ITransientDependency`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#conventional-registrations)

*"ASP.NET Boilerplate automatically registers all Repositories, Domain Services, Application Services"*

As such all you should need to do is change your IEmployeeService to inherit from IApplicationService:

```
public interface IEmployeeService : IApplicationService
{
    int CreateEmployee(CreateEmployeeDto data);
    IEnumerable<EmployeeListDto> GetEmployeeList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need register it in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
}
```

Comment: this process for .net core project DI want to know how to use DI on aspnetboilerplate asp.net-core project controller.

Comment: @shamim - this last comment demonstrates either a misunderstanding in how DI works, or the original question is ambiguous in it's interpretation

Answer (score 1):

Implement `ITransientDependency`.

```cs
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService, ITransientDependency
{
    // ...
}
```

From https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#helper-interfaces:

> ASP.NET Boilerplate provides the **ITransientDependency**, the **IPerWebRequestDependency** and the **ISingletonDependency** interfaces as a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can use registered your class in Startup.cs class.here asp..net core provide inbuild DI.